# Setting Content-Transfer-Encoding in curl post

Tags: apache, http, curl

I am trying to set the header `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` in a curl post, but from what I can see printed on the server the header is not set.  Is there a way to set it?

```
curl --header "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" -F 'file=@test_image_binary.png;type=image/png;filename=test_image.png' http://localhost:5000
```

I'm also seeing that this isn't a valid internet header.  Can anyone confirm?  And can you say why apache would set this header?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's really unusual for a user to set this and highly suspect that you would need to do this unless you're talking to a broken server.